# How to reset a class in Jest/Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, jestjs

Is there a way I can reset the classes so that I don't need to instantiate them for each test? Right now I'm calling: `const animalManager = new AnimalManager();` for each test

I tried this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  AnimalManager.mockClear();
});
but get the error: Property 'mockClear' does not exist on type 'typeof AnimalManager
```

My current test:

```
describe("default subscription actions", ()=>{
  const tigerObserver= new TigerObserver();
  const fishObserver = new FishObserver();

  describe("subscribe", ()=>{
    const animalManager = new AnimalManager();
    animalManager.subscribe(tigerObserver)
    animalManager.subscribe(fishObserver)
    it(`adds new subscribers`, () => {
      expect(animalManager.subscribers.length).toEqual(2);
    });
  })
  describe("unsubscribe", ()=>{
    const animalManager = new AnimalManager();
    animalManager.subscribe(tigerObserver)
    animalManager.subscribe(fishObserver)
    it(`removes subscriber`, () => {
      expect(animalManager.subscribers.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

animal class:

```
interface Subject {
  subscribe(subscriber: Observer): void;
  unsubscribe(subscriber: Observer): void;
  notify(): void;
}

export default class AnimalManager implements Subject {

  public subscribers: Observer[] = [];
```

Comment: Why don't you want to have a new instance for each test? normally a test should not have side effects on other tests, that way even if you remove one `it` all other tests are unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You could move the variable `animalManager` outside of your tests scope, and instantiate a new AnimalManager using the `beforeEach` callback.

```js
describe("default subscription actions", ()=>{
  const tigerObserver= new TigerObserver();
  const fishObserver = new FishObserver();
  const animalManager;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // the animalManager will be reinstantiated before each test.
    animalManager = new AnimalManager();
  })

  describe("subscribe", ()=>{
    animalManager.subscribe(tigerObserver)
    animalManager.subscribe(fishObserver)
    it(`adds new subscribers`, () => {
      expect(animalManager.subscribers.length).toEqual(2);
    });
  })

  /** ... **/
});
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that but got the error: Cannot read properties of undefined when calling subscribe. let playEventRecorder: PlayEventRecorder
beforeEach(() => {
  playEventRecorder = new PlayEventRecorder();
})

describe("subscribe", ()=>{
  playEventRecorder.subscribe(newVistarPlayEventSubscriber)
})

Comment: I think that `beforeEach` runs before each `it`, so in the code above, when calling subscribe, the class has not been initialized, move it inside a `before` or inside the `it`